# C# - Console How to get input every frame

Tags: c#, ascii

So, I was bored and decided to write an ASCII game in C# for the fun of it, and I have drawing, clearing, updating, etc.. Although, I'm stuck at one part, input. I want to get input every frame, without the player pressing enter, So far the player has to press enter, but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ASCII
{
    public static class Game
    {
        static string map = File.ReadAllText("Map.txt");
        public static void Draw()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.WriteLine(map);
        }

        public static void Update()
        {
            Clear();
            Input();
        }

        public static void Input()
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "a":
                    //Do something
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void Clear()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `Input()` void, it gets input every frame, but I only want to get it once, the do a move method or something that I will implement later.

BTW Map.txt displays this:

`###################`

`#                 #`

`# @    #          #`

`########          #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`#                 #`

`###################`

Comment: What do you mean by "every frame"? Do you want to hit the key just once and than move your figure as long as no other key is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine` will wait for the enter-key to continue making the application kind of modal. What you want instead is handle keyboard-events on the concole. So you could use `ReadKey` instead:

```
var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

switch (input.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.A:
        //Do something
        break;
}
```

To hold on moving you may implement this in a loop. The key here is to remember your current action until the next key-event passes

```
int action = 0;
while(!exit) 
{
    // handle the action
    myPlayer.X += action; // move player left or right depending on the previously pressed key (A or D)

    if(!Console.KeyAvailable) continue;
    var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

    switch (input.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.A:
            action = -1
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D:
            action = 1
            break;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question right, but if I did, you can use `Console.KeyAvailable` and `Console.ReadKey` to check if a key is available before reading it.

So something like:

```
public static void Input()
{
   if(!Console.KeyAvailable) return;
   ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);

   switch (key.Key)
   {
      case ConsoleKey.A:
         //Do something
          break;
   }
}
```